# How to resize font on all slides at once in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: powerpoint

I have created a bunch of slides in Powerpoint 2010, and all attempts to resize the text on ALL of them at once, have failed.

I have tried using the "master" slide and it does allow me to change the color and position of the text element on all slides, but despite the master slide showing the intended font size, the real slides do not.

How can I resize the text on ALL 55 of my slides at once in Powerpoint 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to do this with a master slide.  I believe you may be using them incorrectly.  You create a master slide, then fill in the empty text boxes that are created in the slideshow.

At this point, you may be able to resize all of the text by going into outline view, selecting all of the text, and resizing.  You should be able to select individual lines of text as well, and adding to the selection by holding CTRL, and selecting more lines.  Then you can, for example, resize body text, and header text.

### UPDATE

I tried this and it works.

Comment: I'm wondering if this doesn't work for me, because I already have all the slides created.  Ultimately I gave up and just used the format painter very very painfully, on every slide.  =(

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution that I just figured out.  Once you've changed the master, go to each slide and click "reset" on the home bar to force those changes. One click per slide and you're done.

You can also select all the slides and then click on Reset. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the master only affects text in placeholders and then only if the user hasn't selected and formatted the text differently from what the master dictates.

Random text on slides has no connection to the master, so changing the text size on the master won't help.

A macro to change all the other text sizes wouldn't be too hard to write if you just want to make all the text xx points, but it takes quite a lot more work to do a proper job of it (adjusting the text spacing and such rather than just the text size).